# In "Account and device preferences", I tapped on and around my current profile. But why no list of other countries? Why can't I change country?

Tags: google-play-store

[This website](https://www.alphr.com/change-country-google-play-store/) alleges

> 5. Then, tap on the country that you want to set your account to, the available list of countries will vary.
>
> [image]

I tapped and pressed on the red rectangle — then the area around the red rectangle below — on my Android. But no such list ever sprang up, and I couldn't change my country! Why not?

Don't just veer me to [this form](https://www.ghacks.net/2021/06/20/how-to-check-the-country-that-google-associates-with-your-account-and-how-to-change-it/) that I submitted  a month ago, again 3 weeks ago, and third time 2 weeks ago. But I still got NO reply!

[image]

Comment: In which country are you at the moment? As far as I know Google only allows switching if it has detected you to a country you are currently located in. So if you are at the moment in Libya then there will be no country selection available.

Comment: Have you tried the official [Google Play Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7431675?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid)? Did you recently change the country? Note that you can only change the country once per year.

Comment: @Robert Yes, I am in Libya.

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes. official [Google Play Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7431675?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid) didn't work for me. "Did you recently change the country?" No, I am still in Libya. But I travel a lot, and I need Apps for those other countries.

Comment: Then you have to wait and perform the change when you are the next time outside of Libya.